# How to correctly encode categorical for sklearn - memory error for decision tree

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn, decision-tree

it's the first time I approach the sklearn library and honestly I have quite a mess in my head due to the numerous "ways to do things" I found on the internet. 
So I have my cleaned database which looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 246858 entries, 2 to 371527
Data columns (total 11 columns):
name                  246858 non-null object
price                 246858 non-null int64
vehicleType           246858 non-null object
yearOfRegistration    246858 non-null int64
gearbox               246858 non-null object
powerPS               246858 non-null int64
model                 246858 non-null object
kilometer             246858 non-null int64
fuelType              246858 non-null object
brand                 246858 non-null object
notRepairedDamage     246858 non-null object
dtypes: int64(4), object(7)
memory usage: 22.6+ MB
```

So I want to procede with classification on the price variable. Obviously I have to encode the categorical which are:

```
categorical = ['name', 'vehicleType', 'gearbox', 'model', 'fuelType', 'brand', 'notRepairedDamage']
```

And here's the problem. I always get a memory error. I tried with dataframe mapper:

```
encoding = DataFrameMapper([
    (['name', 'vehicleType', 'gearbox', 'model', 'fuelType', 'brand', 'notRepairedDamage'], 
      OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),    
    (["price", "yearOfRegistration", "powerPS", "kilometer"], None)
])
encoding_target = DataFrameMapper([
    (['price'], none)
])
```

And for now this is fine, let's say I want to try a classification tree, I have to create train and test, but before I have to apply transform:

```
X = encoding.transform(data.loc[:, data.columns != "price"])
```

at this poin i get a memory error. And I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for cat in categorical:
    data[cat] = data[cat].astype('category')
    data[cat] = data[cat].cat.codes
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: So, i managed to avoid the memory error. I just dropped the name column. I think that model and brand is enough. I already tried by assigning codes to the cat. Variables. It did work obviously, but the difference in the quality of the algorithm didn't change. Furthermore, with this approach once a car is a number you cant go back. Unless you dont build a dict and check it every time you want to know what car is a certain number.